# Displacement vibration sensor using nidaqmx and python

Tags: python, windows, nidaqmx

I'm trying to make a program in python using tkinter. The user should be able to use a displacement vibration sensor or transducer.

There are mainly two kinds of displacement sensors used for vibration analysis, the eddy probes, and accelerometers with double integration. The current notation to add channels is (suppose that we want channel 1 with an accelerometer, and channel 2 with a velocity sensor):

```
# for the acceleration sensor:
task.ai_channels.add_ai_accel_chan(physical_channel = "your_card_name/ao1", sensitivity = 100, current_excit_val = 0.002)

# for the velocity sensor:
task.ai_channels.add_ai_velocity_iepe_chan(physical_channel = "your_card_name/ai1", sensitivity = 100, current_excit_val = 0.002)
```

I was looking in their [docs](https://nidaqmx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel.html), and they do have notation for the eddy current type of sensors, but haven't found anything on the double integrated accelerometers.

Does anybody knows if there is a specific notation to add a piezoelectric displacement sensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the displacement piezoelectric sensors are pretty rare. I asked in the NI forums, but for some reason I can not post anymore replies.

A way to circunvent this problem is to treat it as an accelerometer, and afterwards do the double integration yourself via software, this means divide your entire resulting array by ω2 your angular velocity (ω = 2πf)